# Method to calculating e in RSA

Tags: encryption, rsa

For simplicity I choose two small primes for `p` and `q`.

```
p=3
q=11
n=33
Φ(n)=20
```

Now we need to find the public key `e`, which has to be coprime with `Φ(n)`. For small numbers like these it is trivial, but how can it be done when larger primes are chosen?

Comment: I thought of protecting this question (as mod), but I've decided to leave it open as beginners may well get a very good explanation during their courses. However, before posting please make sure that your answer is complete, self contained and not a direct copy of one of the other answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy, just pick $e$ as *prime* larger than $\max(p,q)$. As $\phi(n) = (p-1)(q-1)$ it has only prime factors smaller than $q$ and $p$.

You can also do trial and error. If $e$ is prime, the GCD test is very fast. But it is technically not necessary to choose $e$ prime. Also note that key generation is not time critical.

However, often one starts with $e \in \{ 3,5,17,257,65537 \}$ which are [special primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number). Then one choose appropriate $p$ and $q$.
These exponents have computational benefits as they are of the form $2^k+1$. That makes computation of the $e^\text{th}$ power fast. Note that there are attacks for small exponents, especially $e=3$. They are all related to bad implementations, i.e. padding and so on. The RSA-scheme itself is not affected.

Comment: Might want to be more specific about how to _safely_ pick a prime $e$ above $\max(p,q)$ that you're going to publish…

Comment: (otherwise Coppersmith may return to [haunt you](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-68339-9_16))

Comment: I'm looking into an example of RSA and it says that e must be 1 < e < $\phi(n)$  https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~mitra/honors/soln.html If the example is correct, then this answer is inaccurate. Am I right (not sure)?

Comment: I tried with p = 2, q = 3, e = 5. And nothing seemed to work, though e satisfies the answer _just pick e as prime larger than max(p, q)_

Answer (score 3):

For RSA to work, we require that its public key function $x\mapsto x^e\bmod(p\;q)$ be a reversible mapping on $[0,n)$. With $p$ and $q$ coprime, that's equivalent (by the [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)) to $x\mapsto x^e\bmod p$ being a reversible mapping on $[0,p)$ and $x\mapsto x^e\bmod q$ being a reversible mapping on $[0,q)$. With $p$ and $q$ prime, that's equivalent to $e$ being coprime with both $p-1$ and $q-1$.

We could choose for $e$ the smallest integer greater than 1 that is coprime with both $p-1$ and $q-1$ (implying $e$ odd and at least $3$ for large primes $p$ and $q$). That's not too long to find by trial and error. However, it is customary to use $e$ at least 16-bit so that $e\ge65537$. This is mandated by some standards (sometime: for encryption only), and justified if we use an ad-hoc padding (e.g. RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5) because it mitigates padding oracle attacks to some degree.

The most common practice is to choose $e=65537$, and *then* choose $p$ with $p\bmod e\ne1$, which ensures $e$ is coprime with both $p-1$, since $e$ is prime; same for $q$.

When using a secure padding, and no rule forbids it, we can choose $e=3$, and then choose primes of the form $3k+2$.

Answer (score -4):

My RSA generator in Python was a function written as follows:

```
def rsa_gen(p,q):

    n = p*q
    lambda_n = lcm(p-1, q-1)

    e_list = []
    e = 2

    while e < lambda_n:
        if math.gcd(e, lambda_n) == 1:
            e_list.append(e)
            e = e + 1
        else:
        e = e + 1

    e = random.choice(e_list)**
    d = inverse(e, lambda_n)

    return (n, e, d)
```

Obviously, I took the brute force approach for any pre-determined primes P, Q.

Basically, I initialize an array/list as empty, e as 2 since 1 and 0 are not appropriate. Then I run a co-prime check for all values 2 to lambda and populate the list/array with them. Then I pick randomly from that list to get my e.

Regards

Comment: Do you know why $e \in \{ 3,5,17,257,65537 \}$ in generally?

Comment: For p,q of barely secure size (about 1500 bits) if you turn all the matter in the universe into computer memory using only one atom per bit (which is _much_ better than any known technology can achieve) it will be too small to store this list by a factor of over 1e370, a number larger than fits in a Stack comment. Plus you'll need _many_ more universes to power your computation, and even if massively parallelized (and _current_ python doesn't parallelize at all!) it will almost certainly take many times longer than the universe will exist. Therefore, I don't recomment this approach.

Comment: We're generally not looking for code fragments here, Aaron. When we're talking about methods, we presume mathematical constructs and their explanations. Even code fragments should be explained that way; we like to know *why* they follow a specific scheme rather than just *how*. That said, thanks for at least explaining the "how", that's often missing from answers, even on StackOverflow.