# Avoiding overflow when encrypting with RSA

Tags: rsa, implementation, modular-arithmetic

When encrypting with RSA one calculates $ m^e \pmod n $ by doing the following:

```
m^e % n
```

Where $m$ is what we encrypt. Often $e$ is a very big number to make it more difficult to crack.

**So how does one avoid overflow when encrypting?**

Comment: What do you mean by overflow? The mod n ensures that the result will never be bigger than n

Comment: But m^e will be a huge number though

Comment: I think he's not aware that you can do mod n after each intermediate multiply.

Comment: How does that work?

Comment: You're not computing m^e and then reduce it modulo n. You do the mod n reduction after every multiplication. And you compute m^e mod n via something like a square and multiply algorithm where "mod n" is built into the squaring and multiplication. Note, however, that such a simple implementation will leak information on side-channels. So, if you really want to use RSA, you just take a well-known open source library to do that. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the fundamental mathematical operation is not
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbb{N} &\to \mathbb{N} \\
  m &\mapsto (m^e) \bmod n & \text{(elevate to the power of \(e\), divide by \(n\) and take the remainder)} \\
\end{align}
$$
but
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} &\to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \\
  m &\mapsto (m^e) \bmod n & \text{(elevate to the power of \(e\))}\hphantom{\text{, divide by \(n\) and take the remainder}} \\
\end{align}
$$
It is an operation in [modulo arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z/nZ#Integers_modulo_n).

In computations, the elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are almost always represented by the representative in the range $[0,n-1]$. Each elementary operation is performed in $\mathbb{N}$, then the result is truncated modulo $n$. For example, if $n$ fits in $k$ machine words, then a multiplication of two elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ can be performed by [computing the product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm), which fits in $2k$ machine words, then taking the remainder modulo $n$, yielding a representation of the element of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ that is again in the range $[0,n-1]$ and in particular fits in $k$ words. Taking the exponential of a number involves a series of multiplication, each of which is truncated to $[0,n-1]$ in this way so as to obtain the smallest representative of the element of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Even multiplication of two $k$-word numbers can be performed with intermediate values fitting in $k$ words. The naive method is wasteful both in the amount of memory and in that it builds a large number only to divide it afterwards. Methods such as [Montgomery multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_multiplication) avoid computing a double-size number by reducing the size of the result after each intermediate step in the multiplication.

Comment: The technique in the last paragraph, with intermediate values fitting in $k$ words, is also usable for regular arithmetic (allowing a close match of the performance of Montgomery arithmetic, and even better performance for small $e$); see e.g. [this paper](http://users.belgacom.net/dhem/papers/mulmod_cardis98.pdf) of Dehm and Quisquater.

Comment: I really don't understand this answer, what is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, and what is meant by machine words?

Comment: @Gretty $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is arithmetic modulo $n$. It's the basic math in which RSA works. A machine word is the basic unit that computers perform operations on, typically 32-bit or 64-bit numbers; operations on crypto-size numbers have to be decomposed in terms of these operations in order to perform them on a computer.

Answer (score 4):

To clarify a misconception in your question:

It is not true that $e$ is chosen large to make RSA more difficult to crack. Often $e$ is chosen from $\{3,5,17,257,65537\}$. This has computational advances with regard to square and multiply algorithms as mentioned by [Gilles](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/13171/avoiding-overflow-when-encrypting-with-rsa#13172). The choice of $e$ has no influence in the security of RSA primitive (as long as $\gcd(e,\lambda(n))=1$) - although there are flaws in the whole scheme for small exponents.

Comment: Well, as long as $e$ isn't truely stupid - eg $e\neq \pm 1$

Comment: Well of course, also $\gcd(e, \lambda(n)) = 1$ should hold. Like mentioned in OP other question http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/method-to-calculating-e-in-rsa/

Comment: Good spot - didn't notice the other question.

Comment: Also, just to clarify your last sentence above, the "flaws" for small $e$ (like [Coppersmith's attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%27s_Attack)) only appear if one does not use a secure padding scheme (e.g. [OAEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding)). With proper padding, RSA is secure even for $e=3$; without proper padding, it may not be secure for any $e$.